# cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have been trying to makemigrations in my django project but I keep getting this error constanly even though I'm using path instead of url can someone please help me? The error is being caused by the froala_editor path but I don't understand why.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please add code not picture.

Comment: hi, sorry for that. The issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per django docs [here:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url)

django.conf.urls.url() was deprecated since Django 3.1, and as per the release notes here, is removed in Django 4.0+.

so you cannot use fedora_editor with django 4

Comment: oww, I hade no idea. thank you for your reply.